# How to make a method returning XMLError compatible with anyhow::Error?

Tags: rust, xml-builder, anyhow

This is my code (`XMLElement` from [xml-builder](https://docs.rs/xml-builder/latest/xml_builder/)):

```
use anyhow::Result;
use xml_builder::XMLElement;
fn foo() -> Result<()> {
  let mut v = XMLElement::new("v");
  v.add_child(XMLElement::new("e"))?;
  Ok(())
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `XMLError: StdError` is not satisfied
  --> src/xml.rs:78:41
   |
78 |                 v.add_child(XMLElement::new("e"))?;
   |                                                  ^ the trait `StdError` is not implemented for `XMLError`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `FromResidual<R>`:
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Result<Infallible, E>>>
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Yeet<E>>>
   = note: required for `anyhow::Error` to implement `From<XMLError>`
   = note: required for `Result<std::string::String, anyhow::Error>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, XMLError>>`
```

How to I map `XMLError` to `anyhow::Error`? I tried `.map_err(|e| anyhow::Error::new(e))`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: FWIW I've created a [PR](https://github.com/cocool97/xml-builder/pull/10) to add the missing `Error` implementation which when merged will allow to use your current syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `anyhow` docs:

> Anyhow works with any error type that has an impl of std::error::Error, including ones defined in your crate.

Unfortunately, `XMLError` does not implement that trait and, because of the orphan rule, *you* can't do anything about that.

So, `anyhow` won't work out of the box. The `anyhow::Error::new` approach doesn't work either, for the same reason.

Some possible ways around this:

1. Use the newtype pattern. Create a new `struct MyXMLError(XMLError)` and then implement the `StdError` trait for *that*. Also implement `From<XMLError>` for your new type so that things work more ergonomically.
2. Define a bunch of new error types (maybe via `thiserror`) that are more geared towards the *user* of your code rather than the underlying libraries like the `xml-builder` stuff. Have those error types implement the `StdError` type and create them as needed based on what sort of `XLMError` you find.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the error to string, and use the [`anyhow!()`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/macro.anyhow.html) macro to create a `anyhow::Error` from it:

```rust
v.add_child(XMLElement::new("e")).map_err(|err| match err {
    xml_builder::XMLError::InsertError(err) => anyhow::anyhow!("InsertError: {err}"),
    xml_builder::XMLError::IOError(err) => anyhow::anyhow!("IOError: {err}"),
})?;
```